# Prevent an auto reload caused by jquery scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a simple piece of code inorder to have internal links scrolls to specific divs. It works they way I intended but it also reloads the page. The scroll works perfect, just that I need it to not reload the page. Also if this matters, Im using this inside a Wordpress theme I created.

HTML:

```
<a href="#hiremenow">This may sound crazy, So hire me maybe?</a>
<div id="hiremenow"></div>

SCRIPT:
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
         void(0);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Use ajax if you want to prevent reload.

Comment: Why are you calling `e.preventDefault()`? It doesn't look like you need it or the `window.location.hash = target;` line.

Comment: I wonder why do you actually need javascript for this? Doesn't it work simply without javascript unless you want fancy animation?

Answer (score 1):

Return a false value.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
   //whatever...
   return false;
});
```

This means "the click event has been handled, do not perform the standard action".

Comment: This solved a similar problem I was having, but strangely enough, not in all the pages the script was being executed.  On most pages the `return` was unnecessary, but on one page the reload was taking place until I added the `return`.  Have any thoughts on what would effect it?